# PHP - Incrementing element with the same name

Tags: php

If you download multiple files with the same name, a number is automatically added to the file name, for example: `filename(1), filename(2) etc.`.

What I am trying to do is when I am creating a name and there is already a same one, the name I create to appear in the list as: `name(1), name(2) etc.`

This is the code that I use now that only creates: `name and name (1)`, then I get this error when trying to create the next same name, example: `name (1) already exists in your list.`, but I shouldn't get that error and should create the next name in the list: `name (2) etc.`.

```
$deviceUser = "07NAV" . $var;
$sameNames = $mktApi->comm("/ppp/secret/getall", array(
    ".proplist" => ".id",
    "?name" => $deviceUser
));

$i = 0;
if($sameNames) {
    $i++;
    $mktApi->comm("/ppp/secret/add", array(
        "name" => $deviceUser . " ($i)",
        "remote-address" => $IPs[$ipAddress],
        "password" => $devicePass,
        "service" => "pppoe",
        "comment" => $fullAddress
    ));
}
```

Also, I've tried using to use

```
$i = 0;
if($sameNames) {

    for($i = 0; $i < 99999; $i++) {
        $i++;
        $mktApi->comm("/ppp/secret/add", array(
            "name" => $deviceUser . " ($i)",
            "remote-address" => $IPs[$ipAddress],
            "password" => $devicePass,
            "service" => "pppoe",
            "comment" => $fullAddress
        ));
    }
}
```

but when I create only one name in my list, automatically are created X names in my list.

---

Edit after @Martin's answer:

@Martin, thank you for your answer, but the code is not working, maybe is because of me (maybe I did something wrong...)

```
$deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal = "07NAV" . $var;
do {
    // First - check if a duplicate exists...
    $sameNames = $mktApi -> comm("/ppp/secret/getall", array(
        ".proplist" => ".id",
        "?name" => $deviceUser
    ));

    // Second - update and prepare for rechecking...
    if($sameNames === true) {
        $i ++;

        $mktApi -> comm("/ppp/secret/add", array(
            "name" => $deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal . "(". $i .")",
            "remote-address" => $IPs[$ipAddress],
            "password" => $devicePass,
            "service" => "pppoe",
            "comment" => $fullAddress
        ));
    } else {
        $mktApi -> comm("/ppp/secret/add", array(
            "name" => $deviceUser,
            "remote-address" => $IPs[$ipAddress],
            "password" => $devicePass,
            "service" => "pppoe",
            "comment" => $fullAddress
        ));
    }

    // Finally, below, if check failed, cycle and check again with the new updated name...
}

while($sameNames === true);

// Finally, tidy up...
// If you need the original value of $deviceUser, you can retain it.
unset($i, $deviceUserOriginal);
```

Comment: OP, you need to show us the relevant parts of what the method  `->comm` does. The code you currently show doesn't seem relevant to the issue you're describing.

Comment: @Martin, that is the relevant part of the code and yes, I am trying to simulate that activity with a username in a list, not a file. So, when I create multiple users with same name, automatically add a number to it, example: `name, name (1), ... name (10)`.

Comment: @Martin, `->comm` is a function that automatically sends a command to a program that I use, where I want my users with same name to be created.

Comment: What you state such as "This is the code that I use now that only creates: name and name (1)" does not correlate to what you show us as your code.  you also reference a `for` loop but then say it doesn't work without showing what you tried to do with it. We can't help you without seeing your code that attempts to solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: How does the code you show us detect a duplicate name?

Comment: Where is `$deviceUser` set?

Comment: @Martin I've edited the question as you said, I hope is better now.

Comment: ok check my answer that solves your issue as you describe.

Comment: If your code is notworking, what exactly is "*not working*"? Please note the part in your "edit" does not include the top line: `$deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal = "07NAV" . $var;`

Comment: In your edit your syntax `"name" => $deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal . "(". $i .")",` is bad. You should fix this. It looks like what you actually want is `"name" => $deviceUserOriginal . "(". $i .")",`

Comment: ~Your edit is fundamentally wrong; you are misunderstanding the logic flow.  `$mktApi -> comm` should only appear ***ONCE*** and should only appear *after* the `Do...while` whose sole job is to set the value of `$deviceUser`. **THAT** is your issue now.

Comment: @Martin, I forgot to mention that by "is not working" I mean that I get the error "user with same name already exists"... If I put `$mktApi -> comm` after `do...while` I get an error that $i is not defined. If on `"name" => $deviceUserOriginal ...` I put `"name" => $deviceUser`, I get the error "user with same name already exists".

Comment: `$i` is not defined is just a warning and you can simply set `$i = 0;` before your `do...`. Did you fix the syntax error with  `"name" => $deviceUser = $dev...` and it still doesn't work? Check you correctly replaced `$var` placeholder with the valid variable.

Comment: You need to change `"name" => $deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal . "(". $i .")",` this line; this needs to be **TWO** lines:  `$deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal . "(". $i .")";` and then ``"name" => $deviceUser,` .

Comment: I have updated my answer code to better clarify how you should use the `->comm`  method. I trust this will make it work for you?

Comment: @Martin, no. I try creating the second user with the same name, I get the error: "user with  same name already exists.". I tried defining `$i = 0;` before `do...` I creates me one user, then the second one with the same name (0) then after 0 I get the same error as I said.

Comment: How many users does this *script* create per execution? If it's more than one then you need to analyse the logic and reset the counters as required. If it's a class you can set the `$i` to be a class variable so it is remembered on each call of the method.

Comment: Creates one user per execution and no it is not a class.

Comment: Ok. Just todouble check some basics; did you use my revised code from my answer ? If so and it still comes up with errors can you establish if the error is in the *script* of if the error comes from whatever the `$mktApi` class method does? (use error logging etc.). I can't help you further without further information unfortunately, but the code in my answer definitely answers the question you've asked so if there's errors that'll be factors that are not in your question that I won't know.

Comment: Yes, I am using the revised code and I think the error come from the script. `$mktApi` is used just to connect through API to Winbox, that's all.

Comment: You will need to debug your script and see that each method call gives you the expected output and if not explore within the method what parts are jinxed and why. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be you never *recheck* the name value before updating.

You want some very simply PHP loop mechanism like this, first to check and then to update before rechecking; this is a [`Do...while` PHP loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php).

I *assume* `$sameNames` returns a boolean true if the name value already exists.

> So, I found what the problem is... the $sameNames returns an array with the IDs that have the same name

[From comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594390/php-incrementing-element-with-the-same-name/70595280?noredirect=1#comment124899892_70595280)

```
// start your update from here:
$i = 0;
$deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal = "07NAV" . $var;
$sameNames = [];
do {
    // first; check if a dupe exists... 
    $sameNames = $mktApi->comm("/ppp/secret/getall", array(
        ".proplist" => ".id",
        "?name" => $deviceUser
    ));
   // second update and prepare for rechecking...
   if(count($sameNames) > 0){
       $i++;
       $deviceUser = $deviceUserOriginal." (".$i.")"; 
   }
   // finally, BELOW, if check failed, cycle and check again with the new updated name.  
}
while (count($sameNames) > 0); 

// Finally, tidy up. 
// If you need the original value of Device User you can retain it. 
unset($i,$deviceUserOriginal);

//Continue your script from here:
    $mktApi->comm("/ppp/secret/add", array(
        "name" => $deviceUser,
        "remote-address" => $IPs[$ipAddress],
        "password" => $devicePass,
        "service" => "pppoe",
        "comment" => $fullAddress
    ));

// etc....
```

So the `DO` part of the script **always** runs, but only is acted upon on the *second or future iteration* based on the result of the first test in the `while` part.

Comment: So, I found what the problem is... I was playing with the code and I was trying different methods to solve it, but the last one solved it: the `$sameNames` returns an array with the IDs that have the same name, so I was thinking that it doesn't return a boolean and I was right and I removed the line where I declare `$sameNames` as false and I modified the `if` and `while` statements and now it works how I want it. 

Thank you @Martin for your help! I accepted your answer as a solution aswell.

Comment: @MateiNicolae-Daniel thanks I have tweaked your edit and clarified so we can see the evolution of the answer. The answer code checks for the count of elements in the array. Cheers. Glad you found the solution!